# Enable SQL Server express to listen with TCP/IP

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to enable my sql server express to listen with TCP/IP.

The issue I am having is that when I run the below command on my local dev machine and then on the UAT server, I get different results.

```
# Enable TCP/IP
$smo = 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.'  
$wmi = new-object ($smo + 'Wmi.ManagedComputer')

# List the object properties, including the instance names.  
$Wmi
```

Here are my results:

Dev -

[image]

UAT Server -

[image]

I can't enable TCP/IP for the SQL server on UAT because the WMI object does not contain the instance of SQL Server running on it?

Does anyone have an idea why this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the WMI provider was corrupt and had to be recompiled.

Here are a couple of solutions, Option 1 did the trick for me.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/tools/error-message-when-you-open-configuration-manager